# Using a ArrayAdapter won't work with fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-context

I am trying to get an `ArrayList` from an activity and then display it inside a `fragment`  in a custom adapter. The problem it's that I cannot `setAdapter` to do so. The error it says the context it's wrong, when I created the Adapter.

Creare_istoricAdapter class:

```
public class Creare_istoricAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Creare_istoric> {
    private static final String TAG = "Creareistoric_adapter";
    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;

    public Creare_istoricAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Creare_istoric> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        String id_alerta = getItem(position).getId_alerta();
        String tip_problema = getItem(position).getTip_problema();
        String data_ora= getItem(position).getData_ora();
        String stare_problema = getItem(position).getStare_problema();
        String descriere = getItem(position).getDescriere();
        Creare_istoric istoric = new Creare_istoric(id_alerta, tip_problema, data_ora, stare_problema, descriere);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        TextView text_tip_alerta_istoric = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_tip_alerta_istoric);
        TextView text_ora_alerta_istoric = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_ora_alerta_istoric);
        TextView text_stare_alerta_istoric = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_stare_alerta_istoric);
        text_tip_alerta_istoric.setText(tip_problema);
        text_ora_alerta_istoric.setText(data_ora);
        text_stare_alerta_istoric.setText(stare_problema);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The fragment class:

```
public class Fragment_alerte_trimise extends Fragment {
    public Fragment_alerte_trimise(){}
    ListView list_view_alerte_trimise;
    ArrayList<Creare_istoric> alerteTrimise= new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View alerte_trimise = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alerte_trimise,container, false);
        return alerte_trimise;
        Bundle bundle_trimise;
        if (bundle_trimise != null) {
            alerteTrimise = bundle_trimise.getParcelableArrayList("alerte_trimise");
        }
        list_view_alerte_trimise =getView().findViewById(R.id.list_view_alerte_trimise);
        Creare_istoricAdapter adapter = new Creare_istoricAdapter(this, R.layout.istoric_alerte_adapter, alerteTrimise);
        list_view_alerte_trimise.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

The problems it's in `new Creare_istoricAdapter(this, R.layout.istoric_alerte_adapter, alerteTrimise)` , about the context, and is also greyed out, saying it's redundant.

EDIT:

I have changed the code following the answers below, but now when I open the activity that uses the fragment, it does not show the list at all. It's only an blank screen.

The fragment code:

```
public class Fragment_alerte_trimise extends Fragment {
   public Fragment_alerte_trimise(){}
   private ListView list_view_alerte_trimise;
   ArrayList<Creare_istoric> alerteTrimise= new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View alerte_trimise = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alerte_trimise,container, false);
        return alerte_trimise;
}

   @Override
     public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle_trimise = getArguments();
        if (bundle_trimise != null) {
            alerteTrimise = bundle_trimise.getParcelableArrayList("alerte_trimise");
        }
        list_view_alerte_trimise =getView().findViewById(R.id.list_view_alerte_trimise);
        list_view_alerte_trimise.setAdapter(new Creare_istoricAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.istoric_alerte_adapter, alerteTrimise));
}
```

}

The way I created the `Parceable`:

```
Bundle bundle_trimise = new Bundle();
bundle_trimise.putParcelableArrayList("alerte_trimise", alerteTrimise);
Fragment_alerte_trimise fg = new Fragment_alerte_trimise();
fg.setArguments(bundle_trimise);
```

I have the `ListView` created in the layout that's `inflated` by the `onCreateView`, but when I use `getView().findViewById` it says that it `may produce 'NullPointerException'`, and so does the `getContext()`, which says it `might be null`

Comment: `return alerte_trimise;` should be the last statement of the method. Also `bundle_trimise` is not initialized, so the `bundle_trimise != null` is always false.

Comment: Indeed I got that wrong, and changed it. Please check my updated question with the new info

Comment: You can use `view` parameter of `onViewCreated()`, `list_view_alerte_trimise = view.findViewById()`.

Comment: Modified according to the parameters of the method, `view.findViewById()`, but the behaviour it's the same. The list won't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use activity context instead of fragment context `this`. Instead of using `getContext()` or `getActivity()` you should initialize the context on `onAttach` to avoid `NullPointerException`. Check below:

```
private Context activityContext;

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activityContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    activityContext = null;
}
```

Beside this, you have to `return` the view inside `onCreateView` at the very end. Check below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ....

    // use alerte_trimise instead of getView()
    list_view_alerte_trimise = alerte_trimise.findViewById(R.id.list_view_alerte_trimise);


    //use activityContext instead of this
    Creare_istoricAdapter adapter = new Creare_istoricAdapter(activityContext, R.layout.istoric_alerte_adapter, alerteTrimise);

    ....

    return alerte_trimise;
}
```

**In your code,** you try to use `Bundle` after call `return`. That's why rest of your code is **unreachable**.

Comment: I might have managed to solve that issue. Please check my revised question about another issue in the same code.

Comment: The solution that you manage to solve may produce `NullPointerException` that I mentioned in my answer and that also you mentioned in your updated post.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Adding the methods you wrote about above managed to solve the `NullPointerException`, but it still does not behave correctly. The `list` does not show at all

Comment: @Costin, Try to check by debugging that list is not empty

Comment: I changed the code to get the bundle inside `onCreateView`. Still nothing. Debugging showed me that the `list` inside the fragment code it's empty, so the problem it's either when I send it, or when i try to fetch it.

Comment: Yes, So you have to check inside your activity that list isn't empty there

Comment: On the `activity` side, where I create and add to the bundle, debugging showed me that it's indeed created correctly, and the bundle is also created correctly. (4 entries in the list, 4 entries in the bundle)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207961/discussion-between-md-asaduzzaman-and-costin).

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use `getContext()` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Creare_istoricAdapter in your Fragment_alerte_trimise so it needs context. therefor we can give activity context or application context(beyond the activity level)

Moreover...

[getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) - Returns the context view only current running activity.

[getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29)- Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

getActivity() can be used in a Fragment for getting the parent Activity of the Fragment.

Add this code changes to your code.

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use `getContext()` instead of `this`. `this` refers to current object (Fragment), which is not subclass of Context.
2. Create adapter in `onViewCreated()`, because `getContext()` returns null in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Explain downvote, please. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Actually this seems to be right, do not know why someone downvoted. I revised the question about what's not working now